# Need help loading components using vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a main default component called App, in it I have a navigation bar and an image with a button, when I click that button I want to load another view but I don't know how to do this, I have tried to use router.push and router.go but it doesn't do anything, if I use router-view it will load the other components UNDER my "image" component and I don't want that, the only common component I want all my views to have is the navbar.

So here are my components.

*App*

```
<template>
<div>
    <Mynavbar></Mynavbar>
    <Imagewlink></Imagewlink>
</div>
</template>
```

*Imagewlink*

```
<div class=swiper-slide style=background-image:url(img/content/landing/slide-1.jpg)> <br>
   <div class="container">
      <b-col cols="4" md="4" sm="3" class="float-right">
          <b-list-group>     
              <b-list-group-item to="/componenttwo"> link 1</b-list-group-item>
          </b-list-group>
      </b-col>
    </div>
 </div>
```

*I have my route included as*

```
{
    path: '/componenttwo',
    component: componenttwo,
    name: 'componenttwo'
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue... But why not mak your Imagewlink component part of the component assigned to a route and use `<router-view />`?
Otherwise can you perhaps provide a code demo?

Comment: that could be it, but what if i want that route to load when i open the page? I want that component "Imagewlink" to show when i open the page